# Can't start openvpn after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, vpn, openvpn, openssl

I have upgraded from ubuntu 21.10 to ubuntu 22.04 and when i try to run openvpn i get an error message:

```
2022-05-19 11:03:36 Assertion failed at crypto_openssl.c:183 (legacy_provider)
2022-05-19 11:03:36 Exiting due to fatal error
```

The installed versions are:

> openvpn 2.5.5-1ubuntu3
>
> libssl3:amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1
>
> libssl1.1:amd64 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3

Can someone help me solve the problem, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem which was due to loading the openssl libraries included in the Dell Command Configure package.
It was enough to replace the libraries with the default ubuntu ones to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, would never have found that. Since I couldn't figure how to "replace" the libraries, I just renamed `/opt/dell/dcc` to `/opt/dell/dcc_new`

Comment: Also encountered this issue, thanks for the hint Massimo!
@JCBoggio: He meant to replace the libssl library in /opt/dell/dcc with the one that is installed on your system (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so). However I fixed this issue by just deleting "/opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3", which automatically means the system libraries are used, I do not see a reason to replace them or link them to the system libraries. I also did the same btw. with libcrypto.so.3, since I do not want vital system libraries not being loaded, but outdated binaries from Dell.